# AWS structure for container, autoscaler and quick edits of code

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ecs, cicd, amazon-efs

I need to create the infrastructure at AWS with the following conditions:

1. I should use container (Elastic Container Service)
2. I should use autoscaler (I can use service at ECS)
3. I shouldn't have a downtime during big deployment ( I can use github actions with deploy to ECS)
4. **The main problem is in this**:

I should have the possibility to edit quick code during 10 seconds and return the code back if it will be needed.
For example, I will connect to some other EC2, which will have the access to the code (php), which is located at the container or maybe some other AWS service and I will be able to make the edits. Also the changes should be applied to all to all instances, which are under autoscaler.

Please advice, how is better to organize the structure of 4th paragraph. Thanks

Comment: Does using dev9 to make code changes and push to your repo to trigger CI meet your criteria? Why not just make the changes from your workstation and push to your deployment?

Comment: @jordanm, what is dev9?
Can U explain a little more about your idea?

Comment: My apologies, the service is called [cloud9](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/). It's just a virtual workstation that runs in the AWS cloud.

Answer (score 0):

cloud9 is working good. Thanks